# python for line in lines spacing

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open('wordlist.txt') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```

When I run the program I get this output:

```
zeppelin

zero

zestfully

zesty

zigzagged

zipfile

zipping

zoom
```

Is there any way to remove the spacing between the lines?

Comment: `print(line, end="")` - reading the file includes the `'\n'` at lineends- using `print()` adds another one after each line - hence the empty spacing

Comment: also: `print(lines.read())` would print the whole file as well - no need for the for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is reading the lines from the text file, represented below. The `\n` character is shown for clarity.

```
apple\n
banana\n
charlie\n
david\n
```

When you read each line in the file, you get `apple\n`, `banana\n`, `charlie\n`, etc. When you print these out, you'll get an extra `\n` added from the `print` statement.

You have two options for how to solve this:

### Remove `\n` from string:

```py
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip('\n')
```

### Remove `\n` from `print`:

```py
for line in lines:
    print(line, end = '')
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```py
with open('wordlist.txt') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        print(line.rstrip())
```